# Updating JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

The following code is used to get all information and fetch it into a json array. Now I changed the 'author' to userids instead of username strings and I want to get the username strings from another table called 'login'.

But how can I get all 'author'-ids, queue another table and get all usernames with this id and update these in the fetched json array so I echo the usernames with the 'author'- id? I am not really used to JSON arrays, although this code always worked for me until I changed my database structure.

I tried researching some information but I did not find what I was looking for. Please excuse my bad english.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "SELECT title, content, author, id, date, timestamp, importance, version FROM news ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('title'=>$row[0],
'content'=>$row[1],
'author'=>$row[2],
'id'=>$row[3],
'date'=>$row[4],
'timestamp'=>$row[5],
'importance'=>$row[6],
'version'=>$row[7]

));
}
$oldjson = json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your SQL query to a join of 'news' and your 'author' table. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp there is an example for joining two table by customer id

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed! :)